# What site should I use to propose an idea?

Tags: support

I found a new way to define the factorial function and I'm curious as to where I would go to have it reviewed.

Comment: If you haven't had it reviewed, how do you know it's a new way? Well, you could post a reference-request question to mathematics.stackexchange.com, asking, is the following definition of the factorial function new?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it uses geometric integration and is very precise

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I researched the factorial for several hours and found nothing like it.

Comment: Where did you research it? MathSciNet? MathReviews? ZentralBlatt? (ok, those might not be ideal for this kind of search) Just googling for it or checking a few books in a nearest university math library is not gonna cut it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess your comment could be posted as an answer. (At least I personally would upvote such answer.)

Comment: @Jyrki, to be fair, not all amateurs have facile access to MathSciNet and ilk, so asking here (or on MO if sufficiently highbrow) might be the next best thing.

Comment: True dat @J.M. Point taken. The excuse "I researched several hours" just gave me an allergic reaction.

Answer (score 7):

You could post a "reference-request" question to [mathematics.stackexchange.com](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com), asking, is the following definition of the factorial function new?